# Dock right click options list moves position on mouse click

Tags: dock

I'm on lts22.04.
I've moved the dock to the bottom.
When i try to close apps, by right clicking app on dock, then trying to click quit, as i press the button, the position of the options drops and I add to favourites.
I've installed dconf editor, and slowed time down, (thinking it was me that was too slow!), to no avail.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have enabled the 'Auto Hide the Dock' ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I have auto hide active, but i can hover the mouse over the option for as long as I like, but as soon as i try to press a mouse key the dock dissappears, the options drop down and I press the wrong option. not a deal breaker but annoying.

Comment: Issue also raised here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415220/strange-dock-behaviour-in-22-04

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @vanadium, i was able to reproduce the problem when Dock is at the bottom. Works fine for both left and right.