# Strange dock behaviour in 22.04

Tags: dock

I have recently upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 and am experiencing an annoying problem with the dock. I have configured the dock under setup/appearance (Einstellung/Darstellung on my German OS) to be at the bottom of my screen and to disappear unless I move the cursor there. Everything works with a left click as before, but if I right-click on an icon the menu for that icon appears above the dock and if I click on a program in the menu the menu moves downwards to the bottom of the screen and the click is then on another program in the menu.

The only workaround I have found is to click first on the menu-item "Show details" after which the menu moves to the bottom of the screen and I can click on the correct menu-item.

To recap, the menu appears above the dock and then the dock disappears but the menu stays put until I click on it, when it drops down to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Probably the same issue as here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415024/dock-right-click-options-list-moves-position-on-mouse-click

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a confirmed bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1967121

Someone has written a patch with these intructions for installing it:

```
 cd ~/Downloads/
  wget https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/pull/1739.patch
  cd /<email address hidden>/
  sudo patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/1739.patch
```

Unfortunately I can't see which file  I need to patch and the line *"cd /email address hidden>/"* is a mystery to me, I can't think where they want to cd to. However other posters did understand the directions and several have reported that the patch works.

If someone could explain to me how to install this patch I would be very grateful.

Comment: looking at the discussion. Looks like there will be an update for the issue. Hence, probably good to wait for the update to be available or you can opt to help do testing when the proposed is out.

Comment: Now someone has fixed the bug (see link above) but the fix will only appear in 22.10, apparently. I have downloaded the fixed package, gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock - 72~ubuntu6 (~ubuntu5 is the version in 22.04). Now how do I install the later version as this is really hindering my work. If I can't install the fixed package or the patch I'm just going to have to go back to the working 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in the system update yesterday, 31.07.2022.